# SPSS variable scope in nested if

Tags: spss

How would you do the following in spss:

```
var participant_number = 0.

DO IF (condition =1 AND trial_order = 1).
    participant_number = ppnr.
    DO IF (ppnr = participant_number).
        COMPUTE start_condition = 1.
    END IF.
ELSE.
    participant_number = ppnr.
    DO IF (ppnr = participant_number).
        COMPUTE start_condition = 0.
    END IF.
END IF.
```

The variable participant_number needs to be defined for the inner loops and not change throughout the inner if. I am just trying to set a value for all the participant cases if the participant fulfills a condition.

Comment: What do you want to achieve by `participant_number = ppnr.` ?Assign a new value to participant_number ? Based on the code you posted, it seems you are doing that for both branches of the outer `DO IF`. Why not take it outside the `DO IF`...?

Comment: @horace_vr I am trying to remember it. All `participant_number`  cases shoud be 1 or 0 if one of the participant cases fulfils the condition.
This is pseudocode, spss has no idea what var is...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SPSS, in general, (with exceptions, but let's keep things simple for now), variables are global. If they come from the dataset, they can be used in syntaxes without fear of going out of scope.
Note that variables need to be "computed"/created first, before being used. You can do that with syntax or manually in the Data window.

`DO IF` is useful if you want to perform multiple transformations. Otherwise, a structure like

`IF [condition][transformation].
EXECUTE.`

would do the trick.

If I understood your goal correctly, you can re-write your code like this:

```
***create a temporary variable, to check each case if your condition is met. Set the temporary variable to 0 as default value.
compute tempvar=0.
***then set it to 1, if condition is met.
***This is at case level, not participant level.
if condition=1 and trial_order=1 tempvar=1.
exe.
***aggregate the temp variable, from case level at participant level.
***for each participant (ppnr), it will look at all values of tempvar, and set the start_condition as the maximum of tempvar - either 0 or 1.
AGGREGATE
  /OUTFILE=* MODE=ADDVARIABLES
  /BREAK=ppnr
  /start_condition=MAX(tempvar).

***optional.
delete variable tempvar.
```

At the end, `start_condition` will be 1 for each case of a participant if `(condition =1 AND trial_order = 1)` is met for at least one case of that participant; otherwise, it will be 0.

Comment: I would like `start_condition` to be 1 for all the cases of a participant if one of his cases fulfils  `(condition =1 AND trial_order = 1)`

Comment: How is your data structured ? You have more records for each participant ?

Comment: Yes i have about 60 cases for each `ppnr`

Comment: changed the syntax to take this info into account. The `AGGREGATE` command allows for going from case level to participant level.. Is this what you meant by scope in your initial post ?